# How to add external ESLint plugins to Turborepo?

Tags: eslint, monorepo, eslintrc, turborepo

I have just started using **Turborepo**, but could not figure out how to add external **ESLint** plugins (such as [import](https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import) or [unicorn](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn)) to affect all apps and packages.

After adding the external module to the root of my monorepo, I've tried to update the **eslint-config-custom** package to:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ["next", "turbo", "prettier"],
  plugins: ["import"],
  rules: {
    "@next/next/no-html-link-for-pages": "off",
    "import/no-unused-modules": "warn"
  },
};
```

But got anywhere in the project the error:

> Definition for rule 'no-unused-modules' was not
> found .eslint(no-unused-modules)

I would love to get some help and tips on how to add these external rules to a monorepo enviroment.

Thanks!